# Drupal, структура папок

Tags: drupal

Версия Drupal — 7.36.

Обычно в структуре папок этой cms должны быть такие подпапки:

- themes
- sites
- и т. д.

Но из скриншота ниже видно, что этих папок нет. Сам скриншот сделан в filezilla,
когда я находился в корне сейта.

Где могут быть эти папки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Рекомендую уточнить у хостера. На предоставленном скрине нет предпосылок к правильному ответу, а скорее к гаданию. Папок или файлов друпала нет. Скорее возникает вопрос, а почему он там должен быть? Вы его заливали?

Comment: мне дали доступы фтп